# The width of the div is not loaded until the second onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

In short, I wrote a pseudocode, which rolls side menus up to 50px. In addition, I wrote a condition that, when the width parameter is 50px, displays an alert. Everything is ok if it were not for the fact that it only works on the second onclick. Is there any possibility to dynamically load this value when wrapping the parent div that after it rolls the value of the width is already 50px, and not until the onclick is downloaded?

```js
$("#hide").on("click", function() {
  $("#options-menu").fadeOut("fast");
  $("#nav-left").animate({width: 50},500);
  slideMenu();
});
  
function slideMenu() {
  width = $("#nav-left").width();
  if (width == 50) {
   alert('it works');
  }
}
```

```css
#nav-left {
height: 500px;
width: 200px;
background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav-left">
  <div id="nav-title">
   <button id="hide">HIDE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `complete callback` of the `animate` jquery function.
More details can be found here.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```js
$("#hide").on("click", function() {
 $("#options-menu").fadeOut("fast");
 $("#nav-left").animate({width: 50},500, null, function(){
            slideMenu();
        });       
});
  
function slideMenu() {
 width = $("#nav-left").width();
 if (width == 50) {
     alert('it works');
 }
}
```

```css
#nav-left {
height: 500px;
width: 200px;
background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav-left">
  <div id="nav-title">
   <button id="hide">HIDE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could run the slidemenu function after [animation complete](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```js
$("#hide").on("click", function() {
  $("#options-menu").fadeOut("fast");
  $("#nav-left").animate({
    width: 50
  }, 500, slideMenu);
});

function slideMenu() {
  width = $("#nav-left").width();
  if (width == 50) {
    console.log('it works');
  }
}
```

```css
#nav-left {
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nav-left">
  <div id="nav-title">
    <button id="hide">HIDE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://api.jquery.com/animate/

'complete' is the callback function called at the end of the animation - you should put your alert logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Its happenning like that because you have used 500 ms to take by the animation effect. And JavaScript is Asynchronous so it will not wait till the animation will take place and it will call the other function you have called `slidemenu()`

So what you can do is, you can put 500ms delay before calling `slidemenu()` function like this:

```
$("#hide").on("click", function() {
        $("#options-menu").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#nav-left").animate({width: 50},500);
        setTimeout(function(){slideMenu();},500); // This is what I have mentioned above.
});

function slideMenu() {
        width = $("#nav-left").width();
        if (width == 50) {
            alert('it works');
        }
}
```